# PHP Ruta Linux no funciona

Tags: php, linux, windows, variables, rutas

Muy buenas, quiero cambiar unas rutas de windows a Linux, para hacer comprobaciones, y en Widnows tengo estas que funcionan:

```
$BACKUP_PATH = "C:\\\\xampp\\\\htdocs\\\\deimos\\\\vista\\\\backup\\\\backup_";
$nowtimename = date('Y-m-d',time());
$fileName = $BACKUP_PATH.'db-backup-'.$nowtimename.'-'.'.sql';
$handle = fopen($fileName,'w+');
fwrite($handle,$return);
```

Y en Linux como sería, por que lo de haber tenido que poner las cuádruple contra barra en Windows me resulto lioso entenderlo al principio, o lo hice mal pero funciona no sé qué deciros, pero me aconsejaron así y así lo hice, pero en Linux no sé si es problemas de las barras que me falten o porque, pero tengo esto:

```
$BACKUP_PATH = "/var/www/html/dcmcode/deimos/vista/backup";
$nowtimename = date('Y-m-d',time());
$fileName = $BACKUP_PATH.'db-backup-'.$nowtimename.'-'.'.sql';
$handle = fopen($fileName,'w+');
fwrite($handle,$return);
```

Comment: La ruta está escrita correctamente, solo revisa que la carpeta existe y tiene permisos

Comment: Si e copiado los nombres de las carpetas para asegurarme que esten bien escritas y es así, ahora le preguntare al administrador de sistemas los permisos pero el cleinte FTP me muestra: rwxr-xr-x

Comment: como detalle, la ruta de windows que pones de ejemplo acaba con dos carpetas, backup y **backup_**, y la ultima no la tienes escrita en la de linux.

Comment: Vale si fallo mio, ese "backup_" indica como debe de comenzar el archivo que se va a crear, lo acabo de modificar e pedido al administrador que me modificara los permisos de esa carpeta  y ya funciona correctamente, le tubo que dar permisos 777, no se si son excesivos, pero como son usuarios anonimos que puedne entrar tambien ha sido él,el que los aplico y arreglado, gracias chicos.

Comment: agregale un try-catch y envianos el error

Comment: No, ya esta solucionado era lo que dije en el comentario por encima de este lo pondre ocmo repsuesta.

Answer (score 0):

El problema provenia del servidor que alojaba el sitio Web, la ruta esta bien escrita para Linux, pero no tenia permisos de escritura para el usuario que accedia al sitio Web, una vez modificado estos, todo ha funcionado perfecto.